# Cannot make mobile broadband Vodafone USB connection Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking, internet-connection, mobile-broadband

I have Ubuntu 13.04 and I bought yesterday a Vodafone USB stick for internet connection. I am located in Romania.

This is what I've did:

**First Thing**

1. Network Connections, added connection.
2. Selected Mobile broadband
3. Selected my country, and network (vodafone)
4. Selected Mobile Internet (Postpaid) I've called the guy who gave me the stick, and he told me it's Postpaid (anyway, I've tried also prepaid, not working).
5. Just got to general, and checked Automatically connect to this network when it is available, and saved.

Nothing happend.

**Second thing**

I've installed wvdial, set up the configuration to

```
Phone = *99#
Username = internet.vodafone.ro
Password = vodafone
New PPPD = yes
stupid mode = 1
```

When I run `sudo wvdial` I get this

```
--> WvDial: Internet dialer version 1.61
--> Cannot open /dev/modem: No such file or directory
--> Cannot open /dev/modem: No such file or directory
--> Cannot open /dev/modem: No such file or directory
```

I don't have any /dev/modem file or folder, and also no file starting with the name ttyUSB.

**Third thing**

I've took out of the USB port the stick, and run ls -1 /dev > before.txt. Plugged in the stick, and runned again.
The diff before.txt after.txt got me this:

```
9a10
> cdrom2
82a84
> sg2
86a89
> sr1
```

**Fourth thing**

If I run lsusb I get this

**Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 12d1:1f17 Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0a5c:21bc Broadcom Corp. BCM2070 Bluetooth 2.1 + EDR
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 064e:8123 Suyin Corp.**

This one (I guess) is the usb stick

```
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 12d1:1f17 Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd.
```

Any suggestions ?

The usb works fine on windows. I've tried to install it's own software (windows application) with wine, but also got an error.

**UPDATE:**

I've found a command that tells me which /dev/* is my Vodafone Stick.

**sudo lsblk**

```
sr1     11:1    1   128M  0 rom  /media/icebox/Vodafone Mobile Broadband
```

I've changed my wvdial configuration file, and added:

```
Modem = /dev/sr1
```

Now, if I run **sudo wvdial** I get:

```
--> WvDial: Internet dialer version 1.61
--> Cannot open /dev/sr1: Invalid argument
--> Cannot open /dev/sr1: Invalid argument
--> Cannot open /dev/sr1: Invalid argument
```

Comment: http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1197509.html this may help you

Comment: switching tool for controlling "flip flop" in linux based versions

Comment: that thread is not really well organized, I don't even know how to start. usb_modeswitch is already installed into > 10.04 ubuntu version (from what I've read)

Comment: read farbirds suggestion over there,have u cross checked it?

Comment: yes I checked it but... I don't even have windows on it.

Comment: I've updated the thread.

Answer (score 0):

I think you didn't put your settings correctly.

System Setting -> Network -> Mobile Broadband -> Create a new connection

here you already created a new connection, but what are things you put for "choose your billing plan option" ? did your postpaid package listed?

If its not listed, select "My plan is not listed" then you must put correct APN (Access point name ) for your connection. for this you need to contact your service brovider (Vodafone) and ask those settings, and most importantly whether there are Proxy settings.

if there are proxy settings, then after creating the connection,

System Setting -> Network -> Network proxy -> apply those given proxy settings and apply system wide.

Then go to your web browser and apply those proxy settings.

Answer (score 0):

Some USB dongles have their proprietary Windows drivers onboard. When  plugged  in  for  the  first time,  they  act  like a storage device and start installing the Windows driver from there. `/dev/sr1` is such a storage device. It can't be used to make a connection. If the driver is already  installed,  it  makes  the storage device disappear and a new device, mainly composite with modem ports, shows up.<sup>†</sup>

On Linux, the mode of USB device have to been switched as well. Sometimes the manufacturer doesn't provide a driver for Linux, so the program `usb_modeswitch` is needed.

Install `usb-modeswitch` and `usb-modeswitch-data` if they aren't already installed. `usb-modeswitch-data` provides udev rules that automatically recognises and configures common devices, so you probably don't have to manually run the program yourself. Otherwise, run `usb-modeswitch` and pass the necessary information. Usually it's just the Vendor ID and product ID. In your case, run `usb-modeswitch --default-vendor 0x12d1 --default-product 0x1f17`.

If the dongle is successfully configured, devices other `sr1` should show up in `/dev`. They may be called `/dev/ttyUSB0`,`/dev/ttyUSB1`, `/dev/ttyUSB2` or `/dev/gsmmodem`. Try whatever that comes up, if there are several devices, try them one by one using the `Modem` option. For example, I used to have a dongle that works with `Modem = /dev/ttyUSB2`.

______________
<sup>†</sup> According to the man pages of usb_modeswitch.